# Spring Boot Controller Locale Not Changing with Parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, locale, kotlin

I'm having some trouble with using Spring Boot with Kotlin to handle locale.  I created these settings in my application.properties file:

```
spring.messages.basename=messages/messages
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

Then created an autowired instance of MessageSource in my controller:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var messageSource: MessageSource
```

When put a locale in the url as a parameter, the parameter doesn't seem to get picked up when I call `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`, so it is always en_US.  Though, I can manually pick it up using `@RequestParam(value="locale") locale: Locale` as a parameter to my controller function and use it from there in the controller function, but not in other functions.  I thought that spring boot LocaleContextHolder was supposed to hold the current locale based on the request URL automatically for the whole session.

I read an older article that mentioned using a LocaleChangeInterceptor bean as well as beans for MessageSource and LocaleResolver in your main class, but another article said Spring Boot doesn't require that.  I tried it anyway with no difference.  These are the functions I used:

```
@Bean
open fun localeResolver(): LocaleResolver {
    val slr = SessionLocaleResolver()
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US)
    return slr
}

@Bean
open fun localeChangeInterceptor(): LocaleChangeInterceptor {
    val localeChangeInterceptor = LocaleChangeInterceptor()
    localeChangeInterceptor.paramName = "locale"
    return localeChangeInterceptor
}

@Bean
open fun messageSource(): ResourceBundleMessageSource {
    val source = ResourceBundleMessageSource()
    source.setBasenames("messages/messages")
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
    return source
}
```

Any suggestions on what to try next other than capturing the locale manually and making it a parameter in every function that gets called by the controller?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like the missing piece was implementing a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, setting up a `SessionLocaleResolver` bean, and overriding the `addInterceptors` function to manually add my `LocaleChangeInterceptor`.  I used a separate Configuration class to do this.

```
@Configuration
open class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter : WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

    //internationalization beans
    @Bean
    open fun localeResolver(): LocaleResolver {
        val slr = SessionLocaleResolver()
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US)
        return slr
    }

    @Bean
    open fun localeChangeInterceptor(): LocaleChangeInterceptor {
        val localeChangeInterceptor = LocaleChangeInterceptor()
        localeChangeInterceptor.paramName = "locale"
        return localeChangeInterceptor
    }

    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry?) {
        registry?.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor())
        super.addInterceptors(registry)
    }
}
```

I guess I misunderstood, thinking that Spring Boot handled the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` on it's own if you created the proper bean, but I guess you have to still override a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and force the interceptor in there.  If I've missed something and someone has a cleaner solution, I'd be happy to give you the accepted answer since what I'm doing here just feels like a messy workaround.